# How to access UWP devices from C# Winforms App in .Net 5

Tags: winforms, uwp, .net-5

I downloaded some great code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/barcodescanner/  which accesses my barcode scanner really well . I would like to use this functionality from within a Winforms app but I can't seem to load the right library.  If I just add the nuget package I get the following error:

> Error  NU1202  Package System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime 4.0.1 is not compatible with net5.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0).
> Package System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime 4.0.1 supports: uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0)

Any thoughts/help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to host WinRT XAML controls in a Windows Forms app.

Comment: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)